# Crystal Reports: How to hide a group in a grouped report?

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

I have a report grouped by Class1, Class2, Class3, ShortDesc, CreateDate.

It looks like this:

**Class1 Class2 Class3** <- This is GroupHeader1 (I did it this, way to save space)

**ShortDesc - test1** <- This is GroupHeader4

**27.07.2009 10:00**  <- This is GroupHeader5

**Ticket-ID AssignedGroup**
1                 <- this is Detail
2
3

**27.07.2009 11:00**  <- This is GroupHeader5
**Ticket-ID AssignedGroup**
4                 <- this is Detail

**27.07.2009 12:00**  <- This is GroupHeader5
**Ticket-ID AssignedGroup**
5
6

**ShortDesc - test2**

**29.07.2009 10:00**  <- This is GroupHeader5
**Ticket-ID AssignedGroup**
9                 <- this is Detail
11
14

**29.07.2009 11:00**  <- This is GroupHeader5
**Ticket-ID AssignedGroup**
23                 <- this is Detail
28

**29.07.2009 12:00**  <- This is GroupHeader5
**Ticket-ID AssignedGroup**
45                 <- this is Detail

Now I want to hide the *Details*, if there is just one ticket in *GroupHeader5*

This one is acctualy easy. I've said if *Count ({TroubleTicket.CreateDate}, {TroubleTicket.CreateDate}, "by hour") = 1* the Hide.

So let move on.

Now I want to hide *GroupHeader4*, but only if all *GroupHeader5* have only **one** ticket. I tried for hours, but I don't know how to bite this one.

Answer (score 2):

Create a running total that counts records returned in your group, and have it reset on each change of group.  How you do this depends on the version of CR you are using, but to my knowledge it is possible in about all of them.  After that, you put the following in your suppression formula for `GroupHeader4`:

```
// of course you would change '=' to '<='
// if you also want it to hide on 0

{#RunningTotalThatCountsRecords}=1;
```

This should work for most versions of Crystal Reports.